# HFS+ catalog entry has 0 size

Tags: macos, filesystems

I'm working with some code that processes HFS+ Catalog file entries. Starting from OS X version 10.10 some of the entries have zero size while the actual file size is not 0. In other words `ls -l` will show non-zero size, the file can be read but it's catalog entry indicates size 0. Examples are most of the files in /private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users. In OS X up to version 10.9 catalog entries contain file size that exactly matches what `ls -l` outputs. Does anyone know what changes in OS X 10.10 and 10.11 could cause such a thing? Any pointers are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In OS X 10.6, Apple added support for compressed file to HFS+. The details are complex (see [John Siracusa's review of 10.6](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2009/08/mac-os-x-10-6/3/)), but among other things it allows small files to be stored entirely in extended attributes (and maybe the resource fork). Apparently, they started using this for most of the preinstalled user and group accounts in 10.10. Run `sudo ls -lO /private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users`, and look at all the files with the "compressed" flag!